# How to create the custom path for the logs in the domain mode container version

Tags: dns, wildfly, docker-logs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70MGA.png)

I need to change to the custom location path for the logs in the container version

Answer (score 0):

The WildFly image places the server installation at `/opt/jboss/wildfly`, where `jboss` is the name of the container's user ([you can view the Dockerfile here](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/wildfly)). The easiest way to store the logs outside the container is to mount to the server log location (Unix style filepath for simplicity, I'm not too familiar with Windows' formatting):

```bash
docker run -it -v /c/path/to/log_folder:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log:rw quay.io/wildfly/wildfly
```

If you need to move the location within the container, you can edit the config file (`/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`) or use the JBoss CLI on a running container:

```bash
docker exec -it <container_name> /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=FILE:write-attribute(name=file,value={path=server.log,relative-to=jboss.server.log.dir})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i am trying the methods, Could you please mention where we need to change the standalone.xml for the custom path

Comment: <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>   i need to change here  only..?

Comment: Yes, that section should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks cam-rod , In standalone.xml i changed and i removed the relativeto="Jboss.server.log.dir", But it storing in both locations custom&default , same like that i need to change for the workpoint.logs ..? Could you please help me

Comment: I'm not familar with the workpoint logs, but you might find something in the [Admin Guide](https://docs.wildfly.org/27/Admin_Guide.html#Logging).